# Copy and Paste middle range down to last row into another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy only Sheet 1 columns B-I in a sheet with data in columns A-K, but only until the last row and paste it into Sheet 2 Cell A4. I then want to paste this information in another sheet. I have the following line of code set however this only works when I am in SHEET 1 and have cell B1 selected (i'm sure this is because of the selection line i grabbed from the recorded macro). I want to be able to run the code without activating the sheet to speed up the code. How can this be done?

Code below:

```
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B1:I1", Selection.End(xlDown)).copy Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A4")
```

I've Dim'd LastRow already based on the information in sheet 3 to use in sheet 1. This LastRow would be the same LastRow as Sheet1.

Code as follows:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Side note: use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("B1:I" & LastRow).Copy`.

Comment: Thanks on the Long vs Integer tip @BigBen however I still get a run-time '1004' error when I try to run it in another sheet

Comment: See my second comment.

Comment: @bigben This works! Thank you!